# Incremental trace number when features are copied

Tags: qgis, copy

With QGIS 3.12, can I copy and move feature and give the copied feature a tracing `Id` number ?

For example, I have a tree with a numeric field (`Tree number`) 1,2,3 etc.

When I copy the tree, I want this field to "move forward" automatically `+1`.

Comment: Have a look to this plugin : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/ .

Comment: This could lead to duplicate IDs when you copy a tree "from the middle". Why don't you simply run `$id` once you're done?

Comment: Thank you, but i get this error:

Comment: This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS
Plugin designed for QGIS 2.12 - 2.99

Comment: Thank you can you explain me what do you mean to run $id?

Comment: @Erik I understand. Can I run this automaticly? How do i wright it as an "Action"?

Comment: Nevermind @Erik I got it. Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a virtual field with the expression `$id` should do the trick.